# Elixir: VS Code ExUnit cannot find Mix

Tags: visual-studio-code, elixir, vscode-extensions, elixir-mix, ex-unit

I cannot load or run my tests, from within VS Code.

I'm a new user to Elixir, and to VS Code. I'm running Lubuntu 21.10 (Impish). I've downloaded Erlang/OTP 25 (.deb), and Elixir 1.14 (precompiled binary in `/usr/share/elixir`), and can get anything I need running in a Bash terminal. Again, in a standard QTerminal window,
`erl`, `iex`, `mix`, `elixir`, etc. all work fine.

In VS Code, however, I get some errors. I feel stupid, but I'm coming from Sublime Text, so please forgive me.

In the left pane of VS Code, ExUnit shows an error (red):

[image: Test Explorer error]

Clicking on this error gives me this, on the bottom right pane. The command line options, passed to `mix test`, seem to be the default configuration:

[image: Output window: mix: not found]

This result is bizarre to me, because I can open the integrated terminal, execute `/bin/sh`, and then run the exact `mix test` line that's displayed:

[image]

`/usr/share/elixir/bin` has been added to my PATH variable, in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, and `/etc/environment`.

However, I am further confused by all tests being excluded, and wonder if there's some connection to the core issue:

[image]

Note that I can run my tests just fine, using different command line options. I've tried adding tags, but that didn't fix the problem.

I tried Google'ing this, and played around with my settings. Here is what I have configured in the "User" `settings.json`, and I made sure nothing overrides this in "Workspace" settings:

[image]

Changing the `useNativeTesting` setting doesn't solve the problem.

On another (?) note, I get a "failed to run elixir" upon VS Code startup:

[image]

Again, I have *no problem running commands* from a Linux terminal, or from a terminal within VS Code.

Plot twist: If I remove the precompiled Elixir 1.14, and downgrade to an older version, via `apt`, the problem goes away. But Lubuntu 21.10 doesn't offer Elixir 1.14, and I'm really into using the new `dbg()` feature.

But for now, **I cannot load or run my tests, from within VS Code**, apparently because Mix cannot be found.

Comment: Please use the standard way to manage versions https://asdf-vm.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Imms, from the VS Code team, for answering my question on Twitter:

*"Try moving where ever you init mix and elixir (.bashrc?) into your .bash_profile and then logging out and in again or restarting. I'm guessing it's in your bashrc which doesn't run in non-interactive sessions like in tasks."*